# Suddenly, shutdown command can't be found anymore

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, shutdown

I logged in to my Debian 7 server, did an upgrade using apt and wanted to shutdown+reboot using `shutdown -r now` as i did a lot of times before. This time, the shutdown command can't be found anymore. I've already read somewhere that i can try it with the whole path `/sbin/shutdown`, but the programm isn't there, too. I also can't find the reboot command anywhere.

What went wrong? What can i do to restore the shutdown command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$ dpkg -S /sbin/shutdown
sysvinit-core: /sbin/shutdown
```

You probably "upgraded" to `systemd`, removing `shutdown` and friends. If so, you now need to do `systemctl poweroff` to shutdown the system. Why does systemd not provide an alias to shutdown? Why not indeed...

EDIT:

`/sbin/shutdown` should be available if you install the `systemd-sysv` package. It would be nice if `systemd` would recommend or even just suggest `systemd-sysv`.

Comment: You were right! I reinstalled systemd and I've got my shutdown command back where it belongs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: systemd breaking habits :(

Comment: @wurtel As can be seen [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=wheezy&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fsbin%2Fshutdown) the file `/sbin/shutdown` exists in `sysvinit`, `systemd-sysv` and `upstart` in Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Ah, I apologize, I did search packages.debian.org first, but I think I was mentally grepping for `something-systemd`, not `systemd-something`. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 10):

I found this post after an `apt-get dist-upgrade` from Debian stretch to Debian buster left me with no `shutdown` or `reboot` commands.  I tried `apt-get install systemd-sysv` as suggested above and discovered it was already present.

I was surprised to find that somehow my PATH had gotten mucked up and no longer
included `/sbin`.  So `/sbin/reboot` worked just fine.

I answer here in case other folks run into this situation after an upgrade and become superstitious.  The lack of similar concerns on the net suggests this is a rare occurrence.  It is obvious that one should check one's path before concluding a command is missing.  OTOH, I did a `which reboot` and got nothing.  My goto tool failed me and so I missed the obvious.

Comment: This just happened to me and this answer is awesome!